# Angular date pipe custom output

Tags: angular, date, format, pipe, date-pipe

If you take a look in Angular's DatePipe documentation you'll see at the  [pre-defined format options](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#pre-defined-format-options) there's a `'long'` format that looks like this: 
`June 15, 2015 at 9:03:01 AM GMT+1`

I want to achieve the same thing but without the timezone. Eg:
`08 August at 16:06pm`

Here's my code:
`{{ clicked | date: 'dd MMMM HH:mma' | lowercase }}` output: `08 August 16:06pm`
But how can I insert the word `at` between the month and hour?

As a quick fix, I've managed to do it like this:

```
{{ clicked  | date: 'dd MMMM' }} at {{ clicked  | date: 'HH:mma' | lowercase }}
```

But is there a better solution without creating a new custom pipe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally I do this:

```
{{ clicked | date: "dd MMMM 'at' HH:mma" | lowercase }}
```

This way with double quotes the word *at* inside single quotes is interpreted as a `string`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to put your custom string inside your date format just like below,

```
{{ clicked | date: "format'at' format" | lowercase }}
```

output : date  at time

this way you can achieve multiple formate as you want by adding multiple custom data.

```
{{ clicked | date: " date format 'on' EEEE 'at' format" | lowercase }}

// EEEE for Day Name
```

output : date on Day Name at time